# Change icon using jquery on AJAX results

Tags: jquery, ajax, font-awesome

I have a list returned via AJAX after clicking on a link. In the list I have an font awesome link that is used to bookmark the list entry. The bookmarking is done via AJAX and this works fine, my database is update.

However, after the update I want to change the bookmark icon from `fa-bookmark-o` to `fa-bookmark` and add class `green` to make the icon green. This is not working. Code below.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#" id="bookmark" class="bookmark" title="Bookmark" bookmark_id="12345"><i class="fa fa-bookmark-o"></i><i class="fa fa-bookmark"></i></a>
```

**CSS**

```
.bookmark:hover .fa-bookmark-o,
.bookmark .fa-bookmark 
{
color: #27ae60;
display: none;
text-decoration: none;
}
.bookmark:hover .fa-bookmark 
{
color: #27ae60;
display: inline;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on('click', '#bookmark', function(e) {
        var bookmark_id = $(this).attr('bookmark_id');

        $("#loaderIcon").show();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>bookmark',
            data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', bookmark_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success:function(data){
                if(data.status == 'X')
                {
                    $(this).find('i').removeClass('fa-bookmark-o');
                    $(this).find('i').addClass('fa-bookmark');
                    $(this).find('i').addClass('green');
                }
            },
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in the callback of the AJAX call is not the same as on the event handler.

There are multiple solutions, the simplest one is to store a variable in a closure and use that in the AJAX handler

```
$(document).on('click', '#bookmark', function(e) {
    var me = $(this);
    var bookmark_id = me.attr('bookmark_id');

    $("#loaderIcon").show();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>bookmark',
        data: {'<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>' : '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>', bookmark_id},
        dataType: 'json',
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == 'X')
            {
                me.find('i').removeClass('fa-bookmark-o');
                me.find('i').addClass('fa-bookmark');
                me.find('i').addClass('green');
            }
        },
    });
  });
```

There are other improvements possible but I focused on the fewest changes to solve the problem

Other ways: Fat arrow functions, Function.bind

Comment: Thanks Juan, as with Zakaria's answer, this works sort of but removes the class but does not add the new class so after clicking, the icon is totally gone.

Comment: I think this is due to my CSS class that allows the icon to toggle on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the current object `$(this)` in a variable then use it in success callback, since the `$(this)` inside success callback refers to the `jqXHR` object of the Ajax call and no more to clicked `bookmark`:

```
$(document).on('click', '#bookmark', function(e) {
    var _this = $(this);
    ...
        success:function(data){
            if(data.status == 'X')
            {
                _this.find('i').removeClass('fa-bookmark-o');
                _this.find('i').addClass('fa-bookmark green');
            }
        },
    ...
 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Zakaria, I made the change but now the class is removed but the new class is not added so the icon totally disappears.

Comment: You're welcome, glad i could helps. Updated my answer check please.